# laravel eloquent relation joining two tables using intermediate table

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.5

i have three tables **restaurants**, **menus** and **menu_restaurants**
  **restaurants**  
 id(int)
 name(string)
  **menus**
 id(int)
 name(string)
**menu_restaurants**
restaurant_id(int)
menu_id(int)

I have to fetch menus from restaurantId and restaurants from menuId and i have done using sql join query 
$menus = DB::table('restaurants')
->join('menu_restaurants', 'restaurants.id', '=', 'menu_restaurants.restaurant_id')
                ->join('menus', 'menu_restaurants.menu_id', '=', 'menus.id')
                ->select('menus.name')
                ->where('restaurants.id',$id)
                ->get();

need help to do this task using **eloquent relation** in laravel

Comment: Did you create the Eloquent models and relations?

Comment: class Restaurant extends Model
{
    public function menus()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Menu::class, MenuRestaurant::class);
    }
}